Add native code to EAS development build - don't IOS and Android folders get overridden whenever rebuilt?
I think I'm missing something conceptually when trying to add native to code to my react native app built with eas build. I see that I have an IOS folder and an Android folder. Do I add native code to those directly? If so, won't those folders get overridden if I have to rebuild them?
I've been looking at the docs, but I seem to have a blind spot when it comes to this simple question.
Thanks!

maybe I need to create a config plugin? https://docs.expo.dev/config-plugins/plugins-and-mods/#create-a-plugin

A config plugin would be the correct option long term.
The folders will only get "overwritten" once you delete them and rerun npx expo prebuild.
If you want more of an unofficial approach, you could always just save that folder somewhere and in case you need to rerun prebuild, you can just copy over the files again.
